# Expressionengine2: how use a channel form for non logged in people (without expressionengine doing a guest login in the background)

Tags: login, guest

I use a channel form which allows a non logged in person to post to a certain channel. On my entire site (so also on that particular page) I always have a AJAX login dialog, or when logged in a profile menu (and profile dialog). My problem now is when I come on the page where a non logged in user can post - expressionengine automatically does a sort of log in for the guest user in the background. Now this gets me in problems with my profile dialog (which gets loaded for the guest user, while it should only exist for a proper logged in user). And I don't get my AJAX login form anymore (as for expressionengine somebody is already logged in - so the login does not get shown).

Now I am trying to work around it but this is pretty tricky without changing a lot of stuff. Especially because my login is not on a seperate page.

Is there a possibility to allow non logged_in people to get a channel form and post, without expressionengine doing a guest login in the background?

greetings, Rick

Answer (score 1):

What about using [LogMeIn](http://www.putyourlightson.net/logmein/docs) add-on to conditionally log out a user after form submission?

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the logic on your login form so it tests against the group_id instead of logged_in. Then just make sure your channel form user is in a different group than your other users.